# DNA methylation in different positions

Tags: transcription, epigenetics, histone, dna-methylation

I'm trying to understand how does  DNA methylation and histone methylation status of promoters differs given their position in a gene? Does position affect whether they are repressive or activating?

Answer (score 1):

For histone methylation , whether the marks are activating or repressive is determined predominately by which histone tail is modified at which position. DNA methylation by itself however is position dependent; in regulatory regions such as enhancers and promoters methylation tends to be repressive (at enhancers this is mostly mediated by being anticorrelated with the activation mark H3k27Ac) whereas within gene bodies DNA methylation is associated with increased transcription (Ref - http://www.cell.com/cancer-cell/fulltext/S1535-6108(14)00316-X )